# Argument of \cvskill has an extra } when trying to override an existing command

Tags: errors, moderncv, arguments, renewcommand

I'm using the `moderncv` package which already defines the `\cvskill` command.

I'm trying to override/redefine this command with `\renewcommand`:

```
% ...

% param 1: name of the skill / tech / etc.
% param 2: level (for example in years)
% param 3: percent, values range from 0 to 1
% (maincol, lightcol are defined in the code before)
\renewcommand{\cvskill}[3]{
    \begin{tabular*}{1\mpwidth}{p{0.72\mpwidth} r}%
        \textcolor{black}{\textbf{#1}} & \textcolor{maincol}{#2} \\%
    \end{tabular*}%
    \hspace{4pt}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,rounded corners=2pt,very thin]%
        \fill [lightcol] (0,0) rectangle (1\mpwidth, 0.15);%
        \fill [maincol] (0,0) rectangle (#3\mpwidth, 0.15);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

% ...

\cvskill{Internet of Things}{5+ yrs}{1} \\ [-2pt]
```

I get this error message:

```
! Argument of \cvskill has an extra }.<inserted text>\par \begin{document}
! Paragraph ended before \cvskill was complete. <to be read again>\par \begin{document}
```

It only compiles without error(s) when I'm using `\newcommand` with another name to define it like `\cvskillbis` for example.

How can I override `\cvskill` command in the appropriate way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain better what you want to do with the new command, can you show a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue?

Comment: Thanks @Mensch!

Comment: the original definition has only one argument, and it is used in the code. Changing that to a command that takes three arguments is not a good idea.